Why does $k=-2$ always maximize $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac k x \right)^x-e^k}{\left(1+\frac C x\right)^x-e^C}$ for $C>0$ and $k\le0$?
Let $C>0$ and consider $$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac k x \right)^x-e^k}{\left(1+\frac C x\right)^x-e^C}$$
as a function of $k$, where $k \le 0$. Prove its maximum is always achieved at $k=-2$.
Define $f(a,b) = (1+b/a)^a - e^b $, then our limit is equal to
$$=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x,k)}{ f(x, C)}$$
Clearly for all $b \neq 0$, $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x, b) = 0$, so we are working with an indeterminate form 0/0.
Now, the question is to find $k \le 0$ maximizing said limit. It doesn't seem right that $k=-2$ could possibly maximize this limit no matter the value of $C$, but according to my preliminary calculations it appears to be true. The question is first to prove the result, that no matter what $C$ you choose, $k=-2$ maximizes the limit for $k \le 0$. But the other question is how to interpret such a result?
Why specifically would $(1-2/x)^x - \frac 1{e^2}$ be the unique function which maximizes the ratio of it to $(1+C/x)^x-e^C$ for ANY $C>0$? Intuitively I would think that depending on $C$, we would be able to use a formula or approximation scheme to recognize the negative $k$ for which the ratio is maximized. But apparently it is a constant, always $k=-2$ works best.
I tried differentiating both sides but it became incredibly messy - what is the simplest way to see this?

Recall that as $t\to0$,
$$\ln(1+t)=t-\frac{t^2}2+o(t^2)$$
and
$$e^t-1\sim t,$$
where $\sim$ is the symbol of asymptotic equivalence.
Now for $k$ fixed, as $x\to\infty$, $\frac k x\to0$ hence$$\begin{align}f(x,k)&:=\left(1+\frac k x \right)^x-e^k\\&=e^{x\ln\left(1+\frac k x \right)}-e^k\\
&=e^k\left(e^{-\frac{k^2}{2x}+o(1/x)}-1\right)\\
&\sim-\frac{k^2}{2x}e^k
\end{align}$$
and therefore,
$$\frac{f(x,k)}{ f(x, C)}\to
\frac{k^2e^k}{C^2e^C}.$$
The maximum of $k^2e^k$ for $k\le0$ is at $k=-2$.

isn't the fact $e^k (e^{-k^2/2x+o(1/x)} - 1) \sim \frac{-k^2}{2x}e^k$ derived only from the expansion of that function near $x=0$? Which wouldn't apply since we are taking $x \to \infty$? I understand $x \ln (1+k/x) \sim k - k^2/2x + o(k^2)/o(x)$ and the factoring out of $e^k$ below it. But the Taylor series for that would be like $-k^2x/2 - k^3x/2 + k^4(x-2)x/8 + \cdots$. I guess I follow your argument but I just need to convince myself that series expansion works on the last line. Clearly it does agree with the right answer of $k=-2$.

To ask a followup, why expanding $e^k (e^{-k^2/2x} - 1)$ as $-k^2/2x \cdot e^k$ valid as $x \to \infty$?

I see, it is because we get that $\sim -k^2 e^k /2 + \frac{e^k k ^4 x^2}8 - \cdots$ when using the Taylor series for it on $x$ which would converge everywhere. But since $x \to \infty$, this looks to be blowing up -- not sure still!

I am not using power series. I only expand $e^t$ near $t=0$ at the order $1$ (and $\ln(1+t)$ at the order $2$). Also,  I use $\sim$ with its precise meaning (follow the link just added).
